# what is use of "Show time line option " for List View Web Part In SPD2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

Please see this image what is use of this?
[image]

Comment: It will show the time line of the tasks. Create 2-3 tasks with proper start and end date and see the output. Check this link for further reference: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/09/how-to-use-the-timeline-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeline has been introduced in SharePoint 2013 to add a new functionality taken from MS project server to display the timeline of the Tasks.

[image]

For example, if you have some important tasks in your list , you can add those tasks to the timeline , to compare the due dates for those tasks.and Each task list now has a default view that contains a graphical timeline at the top of the list.

Also, you can edit Tasks within Timeline easily

[image]

Other feature you can see it at [Time Line Task Lists in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/task-lists-in-sharepoint-2013)

**[Update]**

You should be aware of The timeline is should be shown in the task list or a custom list with task content type, so if you have enabled the `content type` with `Tasks item` you can get `show Timeline` option at your custom list view web part property . and 
to hide it , Edit web part just uncheck `show Timeline`